# Maclaurin Series $ \int \frac{\sin(x)}{5x} $

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am supposed to evaluate the indefinite integral as an infinite series centered at $ x=0 $ and give the first five non-zero terms of the series.

$ \int \frac{\sin(x)}{5x} $

Here is what I have done so far:

$ g(x) = \sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $

$ \int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n }{(2n+1)!} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{5x} $

$ \frac{1}{5}\int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n }{(2n+1)!} x^{2n} $

$ \frac{1}{5} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n }{(2n+1)!} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} $

For $ n=0 $, $ \frac{1}{5}(x)$

$ n=1 $, $ \frac{1}{5}(\frac{-1}{3!} \frac{x^3}{3})$

$ n=2 $, $ \frac{1}{5}(\frac{1}{5!} \frac{x^5}{5})$

$ n=3 $, $ \frac{1}{5}(\frac{-1}{7!} \frac{x^7}{7})$

$ n=4 $, $ \frac{1}{5}(\frac{1}{9!} \frac{x^9}{9})$

And sum them.

I've done this a few different ways and am getting the same result. Can anyone shed some light on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Nowhere, why ??

Comment: The online program I have to submit this to is yelling at me that I've done something not correct.

Comment: May be, you must explicitely use the values of the factorials.

Comment: Did you input the solution correctly to that program ?

Comment: I have checked again and again and just tried computing the factorials and still it is taking issue. Thank you for checking the work.

Answer (score 3):

Your result is perfectly good (before the expansion of the factorials, what I cannot check).

Forgetting the signs, the denominators are (as you wrote)
$$5 \qquad 5\times 3!\times 3=90\qquad 5\times 5!\times 5=3000 \qquad 5\times 7!\times 7=176400$$ $$\qquad 5\times 9!\times 9=16329600$$ Making then $$\frac{x}{5}-\frac{x^3}{90}+\frac{x^5}{3000}-\frac{x^7}{176400}+\frac{x^9}{16329600}
   +O\left(x^{11}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

So, what happened was when I took the indefinite integral, to cover all potential functions which satisfy the indefinite integral, + C needs to be included.

Comment: For sure ! You and I missed the famous constant !! Shame on me. Cheers